# SQL Split function using two characters delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to break a string on the basis of words or characters of not same length. I'm using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

```
String ===> 'term1 OR term2'
```

So I want ti break it based on 'OR' so the result would be

```
term1
term2
```

It can also be like this

```
term3 AND term4
```

So it would bebroken on the basis of AND giving us the result

```
term3
term4
```

Comment: Standard single char delimiter string splitting function can be used with space delimiter and you simply ignore returned rows where value is 'OR' and 'AND'.

Comment: But perhaps you have over-simplified your sample data?

Comment: If _I'm using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio_ means that OP uses SQL Server 2014, then `STRING_SPLIT()` is not available.

Comment: String splitting in sql server is discussed **every day**. It matters not which version of sql server OP is using - somewhere someone has posted a function to do that for versions prior to the native tsql function as well as versions that support more than just a single character delimiter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One method is to use `string_split()` -- with a twist because it does not support multi-character separators:

```
select *
from string_split( replace(@str, ' OR ', '|'), '|')
```

Note:  This assumes that `|` is not a valid "word" character.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d47bad8dd9c6c3ae24c5ea1e1313e7ca) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Well if the extent of your use cases are splitting inputs with single `OR` or `AND`, then the base string functions can handle this:

```
SELECT LEFT(col, CHARINDEX(' OR ', col) - 1) AS term FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX(' OR ', col) + 4, LEN(col)) FROM yourTable;
```

**Data:**

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'term1 OR term2' AS col
)
```